# Why is this Python code running in a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file using python. Have two functions, one to get the file name and open the file, second to check if the extension is valid. Check for a period, 3 chars with no upper case, numeric or special chars.

e.g. first pass testfile.txt will run fine. but if I run the code again and test with variables like test.123 and then enter testfile.txt, goes to the while loop,but if I go with test.abc, the response is correct. then if enter testfile.txt or any other correct file after a wrong entry the code takes me back to the while loop. Where did i make the mistake.

```
def openfiles():
    """
        this function to accept the file name and open it.

    :rtype : object
    """
    found_file = False
    while not found_file:
        try:
            filename = input("Please provide the name of the file")
            ext_check = checkFileEXT(filename)
            if ext_check is True:
                input_file = open(filename)
            found_file = True
        except IOError:
            print("The requested file was not opened. Either the file name or extension was not correct. \
            Please try again")
    return input_file


def checkFileEXT(filename):
    period = "."
    index = filename.find(period)
    request_file_name = False
    if index == -1:
        request_file_name = True
    else:
        provided_ext = filename[index + 1:len(filename)]
        for char in provided_ext:
            if char not in ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "0", "p", "q", "r", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z"):
                request_file_name = True
    while request_file_name is True or len(provided_ext) != 3:
        print("The file name provided was not correct")
        openfiles()
    return True
print(openfiles())
```

Another issue I have is that breakpoints are getting over ridden. It seems to Run the code even in Debug. This will happen on the second pass.

Comment: the second function is not showing correctly.

Comment: With rare exceptions, the while loop is not idiomatic in Python unless it is `while True:`.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that no contemporary filesystem makes a distinction between a file's name and its extension?

Comment: I am new to coding, and was trying to figure out why the code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
while request_file_name is True or len(provided_ext) != 3:
```

There is nothing to set `request_file_name` to `False` or change the length of `provided_ext`. Therefore, the loop either runs ones or forever.

Comment: Wont the request_file_name = False change the when the checkFileEXT(filename) is called again.

Comment: Two (recursive) calls have independent local variables.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do the check of the file would be as follows:

```
new_file = open_file()
while check_file(new_file) is False:
    new_file = open_file()

print(new_file)
```

This reduces the complicated logic of your two functions calling each other multiple times, and decouples them from each other. You will need to re-factor your code a bit, as this only shows the basic logic.

Comment: also, i would recommend using pythons built-in `isalpha()` method instead of `if char not in (“a”, “b”, “c”, ...`